# Calling WCF Services from web site: one call or many?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

This may sound like a very stupid question - and probably is!

For an ASP.Net website with calls through to a WCF Service:

Three web clients click the button that calls the WCF Service simultaneously.

Does the web server make 3 concurrent calls? (e.g. WCF Service receives 3 concurrent calls) one on behalf of each web client?

My guess is that it must do this...but I suddenly doubted myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, however thats why we use "Session" variables to store instances of regularly used objects in each request by same web client, that reduces object creation/destruction overhead on the server.

Comment: Thanks.  My problem is that the object in question is a COM+ component that also requires a logon - and the component (even if pooled) can only log on once at a time.  Logon takes 3/4 seconds...meaning session variables/per session calls are out.

Comment: Apols:  Would "HttpContext.Current.Application" on a website exist per user, per site, per session?  I think this is "for the application itself, i.e. once for everyone. ?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Application is for all, regardless of user, its per site, where else HttpContext.Current.Session is for current user per session, you have to logon only once when you are creating and storing a new object for first time in session, for next calls, logon will not be necessary as it will be reused from session.

Comment: Thanks Akash.  Answers the question enough for me :)